# Can I use createMediaElementSource() without a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, visualization, web-audio-api, pcm

I am streaming PCM audio chunks by emitting them via socket.io. Then on the browser am using [pcm-player](https://github.com/samirkumardas/pcm-player) to feed the the data as they are received.

I can hear the sound clearly, and everything seems fine.
My issue is now that I want to visualize the sound that I am receiving, but everywhere I looked, I stumble on the same part. I need to create a `AudioContext` analyzer, which needs a source. The only way I can create a source, is by linking it to an `<audio>` tag `createMediaElementSource()`

My question is: How can I connect the `AudioContext` analyzer to the PCMPlayer source?
This is what the PCMPlayer contains:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `gainNode` is what PCM Player uses as the final `AudioNode` in its internal graph.

https://github.com/samirkumardas/pcm-player/blob/ab0c17a2ec75c99abe853eacf47a0113651a7636/pcm-player.js#L50-L52

You can just use that as an input for your visualization. But if you want to do so you need to re-use the `AudioContext` used by PCM Player. It's not possible to connect an `AudioNode` created on one `AudioContext` to another `AudioContext`.

The following should work:

```
const analyserNode = AnalyserNode(pcmPlayer.audioCtx);

pcmPlayer.gainNode.connect(analyserNode);
```